# javascript 2D arrays 'for loops' setting every SECOND ARRAY VALUE

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

function trying to set certain elements in a 2D array to zero but EVERY nth element being set. `fleetline[i][j]=0` sets EVERY line 'j' element to 0. Why is this?

```
    function hasMissileHit() {

        var i;
        var j;
        var leftX;
        var rightX;
        var upperY;
        var lowerY;

        for (i = 0; i < numberOfLines; i++) {

            for (j = 0; j < numOfInvadersInLine; j++) {

                leftX = xPos + (22 * block * j);
                rightX = xPos + (22 * block * j) + (11 * block);
                upperY = yPos + ((((8 * block) + ySpaceBetweenInvaders) * i));
                lowerY = yPos + ((((8 * block) + ySpaceBetweenInvaders) * i) + (8 * block));

                if (fleetLine[i][j]) {

                    if (baseMissileYPos <= lowerY && baseMissileYPos >= upperY) {
                        if (baseMissileXPos >= (leftX - 2) && baseMissileXPos <= (rightX)) {
                            baseMissileLaunch = false;
                            baseMissile = 0;
                            context1.clearRect(baseMissileXPos, baseMissileYPos, baseMissileWidth, baseMissileHeight);
                            killInvader(leftX, upperY);

                            fleetLine[i][j] = 0;

                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    function killInvader(invX, invY) {

        var xI = invX - 4;
        var yI = invY - 15;

        context1.clearRect(xI, yI, invaderWidth + 8, invaderHeight + 15);

    }
```

Comment: Could you provide an example of expected and actual output?

Comment: 1) i think you want to return (or return true) once the missile hits. 2) you should iterate downstairs towards upper part => reverse your loop on i. 3) could you show the code for killInvader ?

Comment: fleetLine[i][j] is a 2D array that represents a matrix of objects. A value of "1" means the object exists - "0" means no longer treat that element in the array or matrix as there.

Comment: if the missile is kept alive after killing an invader, it will kill them all in a column. Could you make sure this is not what's happening ? Personally i would console.log('entering hasMissileHit') in function start and console.log('hit at ' + i + ' ' + j) on hit to see what's happening.

Comment: missile is definitely killed in the explosion!

Comment: I think there's a problem in how the fleet is set up. Fleet[i][j]. I'll check my code more.

Comment: Ok. Since you seem to update the canvas (rather than redraw it each time), couldn't it be that invaders are invisible but still are declared as alive in the fleet array ?